# Regex Protein Digestion

Tags: ruby, regex, bioinformatics

So, I'm digesting a protein sequence with an enzyme (for your curiosity, Asp-N) which cleaves before the proteins coded by B or D in a single-letter coded sequence.  My actual analysis uses `String#scan` for the captures.  I'm trying to figure out why the following regular expression doesn't digest it correctly...

```
(\w*?)(?=[BD])|(.*\b)
```

where the antecedent `(.*\b)` exists to capture the end of the sequence.
For:

```
MTMDKPSQYDKIEAELQDICNDVLELLDSKGDYFRYLSEVASGDN
```

This should give something like: `[MTM, DKPSQY, DKIEAELQ, DICN, DVLELL, DSKG, ... ]` but instead misses each D in the sequence.

I've been using http://www.rubular.com for troubleshooting, which runs on 1.8.7 although I've also tested this REGEX on 1.9.2 to no avail.  It is my understanding that zero-width lookahead assertions are supported in both versions of ruby.  What am I doing wrong with my regex?

Comment: What method are you using? `String#scan`, `String#split` or something else?

Comment: +1 What a great question. I did not expect the results you got, and further analysis taught me a little something about the way the regex handles repeated zero-width matches.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your statement "which cleaves before the proteins coded by B or D". As I understand things, **B** is the single letter code for **either** D or N (where it is not known whether the residue is Asp or Asn)? Can Asp-N cleave before Asn?

Comment: @TomD Sorry if my phrasing isn't clear.  Asp-N doesn't cleave after Asn, but for analysis purposes, it is assumed that a cleavage occurs, rather than assuming that B represents N.  This increases the number of peptide fragments that results, but ensures that you haven't neglected a possible fragment.  Makes sense, right?

Comment: @Ryanmt OK, I get the idea now :-)  Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: @Ryanmt On reading your question, I tried to use _Mathematica_ to answer it.  I found it was not as easy as it looked at first sight so I [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6187973/499167) a variant to the Mathematica tag at SO.  You may be interested in the answers, expecially the [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187973/stringcut-to-the-left-or-right-of-a-defined-position-using-mathematica/6188386#6188386) one. (The original protease example is hypothetical!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to support this is to split on the zero-width lookahead:

```
s = "MTMDKPSQYDKIEAELQDICNDVLELLDSKG"
p s.split /(?=[BD])/
#=> ["MTM", "DKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG"]
```

For understanding as to what was going wrong with your solution, let's look first at your regex versus one that works:

```
p s.scan(/.*?(?=[BD]|$)/)
#=> ["MTM", "", "KPSQY", "", "KIEAELQ", "", "ICN", "", "VLELL", "", "SKG", ""]

p s.scan(/.+?(?=[BD]|$)/)
#=> ["MTM", "DKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG"]
```

The problem is that if you can capture zero characters and still match your zero-width lookahead, you succeed without advancing the scanning pointer. Let's look at a simpler-but-similar test case:

```
s = "abcd"
p s.scan //      # Match any position, without advancing
#=> ["", "", "", "", ""]

p s.scan /(?=.)/ # Anywhere that is followed by a character, without advancing
#=> ["", "", "", ""]
```

A naive implementation of `String#scan` might get stuck in an infinite loop, repeatedly matching with the pointer before the first character. It appears that once a match occurs without advancing the pointer the algorithm forcibly advances the pointer by one character. This explains the results in your case:

1. First it matches all the characters up to a B or D,
2. then it matches the zero-width position right before the B or D, without moving the character pointer,
3. as a result the algorithm moves the pointer past the B or D, and continues on after that.

Comment: Perhaps I should simplify, as the other answer does seem to work, but this is really what I was looking for: Understanding!  Thank you for explaining why my Regular Expression was broken!

Comment: @Ryanmt I'm glad I could help. I've also modified my regex to show you a simpler way to capture the end of the sequence if you wanted to use this rather than the simpler split-based solution.

Comment: Ah. I've read about that but hadn't applied it to my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Basically, you want to cut you string before each B or D?

```
"...".split(/(?=[BD])/)
```

Gives you

```
["MTM", "DKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG", "DYFRYLSEVASG", "DN"]
```