# 'StringCut' to the left or right of a defined position using Mathematica

Tags: string, wolfram-mathematica, bioinformatics

On reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6052211/499167), I thought the following problem would be simple using `StringSplit`

Given the following string, I want to 'cut' it to the left of every "D" such that:

1. I get a **List** of fragments (with sequence unchanged)
2. `StringJoin`@fragments gives back the original string (but is does not matter if I have to reorder the fragments to obtain this). That is, sequence within each fragment is important, and I do not want to lose any characters.

(The example I am interested in is a protein sequence (string) where each character represents an amino acid in one-letter code.  I want to obtain the theoretical list of ALL fragments obtained by treating with an enzyme known to split before "D")

```
str = "MTPDKPSQYDKIEAELQDICNDVLELLDSKGDYFRYLSEVASGDN"
```

The best I can come up with is to insert a space before each "D" using `StringReplace` and then use `StringSplit`.  This seems quite awkward, to say the least.

```
frags1 = StringSplit@StringReplace[str, "D" -> " D"]
```

giving as output:

```
{"MTP", "DKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG", "DYFRYLSEVASG", "DN"}
```

or, alternatively, using `StringReplacePart`:

```
frags1alt = 
 StringSplit@StringReplacePart[str, " D", StringPosition[str, "D"]]
```

Finally (and more realistically), if I want to split before "D" provided that the residue immediately preceding it is not "P" [ie P-D,(Pro-Asp) bonds are not cleaved], I do it as follows:

```
StringSplit@StringReplace[str, (x_ /; x != "P") ~~ "D" -> x ~~ " D"]
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Speed is not necessarily an issue.  I am unlikely to be dealing with strings of greater than, say, 500 characters. I am using Mma 7.

**Update**

I have added the bioinformatics tag, and I thought it might be of interest to add an example from that field.

The following imports a protein sequence (Bovine serum albumin, accession number 3336842) from the [NCBI database](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) using [eutils](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/nbk25500/) and then generates a (theoretical) [trypsin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypsin) digest.  I have assumed that the enzyme tripsin cleaves between residues A1-A2 when  A1 is either "R" or "K", provided that A2 is not "R", "K" or "P".  If anyone has any suggestions for improvements, please feel free to suggest modifications.

Using a modification of sakra's method ( a carriage return after '?db=' possibly needs to be removed):

```
StringJoin /@ 
   Split[Characters[#], 
    And @@ Function[x, #1 != x] /@ {"R", "K"} || 
      Or @@ Function[xx, #2 == xx] /@ {"R", "K", "P"} &] & @
 StringJoin@
  Rest@Import[
    "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=\
protein&id=3336842&rettype=fasta&retmode=text", "Data"]
```

My possibly ham-fisted attempt at using the regex method (Sasha/WReach) to do the same thing:

```
StringSplit[#, RegularExpression["(?![PKR])(?<=[KR])"]] &@
 StringJoin@Rest@Import[...]
```

**Output**

```
{MK,WVTFISLLLLFSSAYSR,GVFRR,<<69>>,CCAADDK,EACFAVEGPK,LVVSTQTALA}
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard.  Thanks for those nice edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some alternate solutions:

Splitting by any occurrence of "D":

```
In[18]:= StringJoin /@ Split[Characters["MTPDKPSQYDKIEAELQDICNDVLELLDSKGDYFRYLSEVASGDN"], #2!="D" &]
Out[18]:= {"MTP", "DKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG", "DYFRYLSEVASG", "DN"}
```

Splitting by any occurrence of "D" provided it is not preceded by "P":

```
In[19]:= StringJoin /@ Split[Characters["MTPDKPSQYDKIEAELQDICNDVLELLDSKGDYFRYLSEVASGDN"], #2!="D" || #1=="P" &]
Out[19]:= {"MTPDKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG", "DYFRYLSEVASG", "DN"}
```

Comment: I also use the same type of `Split` construct for these types of manipulations.  @TomD don't feel obliged to keep the characters in one string, it's often advantageous to work with a character list instead.

Comment: Thanks I like this one.  The regex solution is also pretty neat.

Answer (score 7):

I can not build anything much simpler that your code. Here is a regex code, which you might happen to like:

```
In[281]:= StringSplit@
 StringReplace[str, RegularExpression["(?<!P)D"] -> " D"]

Out[281]= {"MTPDKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG", \
"DYFRYLSEVASG", "DN"}
```

It uses negative lookbehind pattern, borrowed from [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

---

**EDIT** Adding [WReach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211232/wreach)'s cool solution:

```
In[2]:= StringSplit[str, RegularExpression["(?<!P)(?=D)"]]

Out[2]= {"MTPDKPSQY", "DKIEAELQ", "DICN", "DVLELL", "DSKG", \
"DYFRYLSEVASG", "DN"}
```

Comment: +1 You can simplify this to `StringSplit[str, RegularExpression["(?<!P)(?=D)"]]`.

Comment: +1, I learned a couple of things about regular expressions that I didn't know, although that isn't saying much. Just to make sure I understand it, the updated solution uses negative look-behind whenever it matches the `D` via positive look-ahead, and the positive look-ahead is what allows the next string to start with `D`. A simple illustration is to try this with `"(?<!P)D"`, and compare.

Comment: @rcollyer Your analysis is correct.  `StringSplit` normally excludes all occurrences of the delimiters that it finds.  In this case, the delimiters are empty strings -- empty strings that are not preceded by a *P* but that are followed by a *D*.

Comment: @WReach. I really like this solution. I have learned a lot from your answer.  Thanks. Regular Expressions (within Mathematica) open up possibilities that I have never really thought about. If I could, I would accept both your answer and Sakra's.

Answer (score 3):

Your first solution isn't that bad, is it? Everything that I can think of is longer or uglier than that. Is the problem there might be spaces in the original string?

```
StringCases[str, "D" | StartOfString ~~ Longest[Except["D"] ..]]
```

or

```
Prepend["D" <> # & /@ Rest[StringSplit[str, "D"]], First[StringSplit[str, "D"]]]
```

Comment: Thanks.  These are also nice solutions. As I said above, I have learned a lot from these answers, and I have had to spend a bit of time going through them.  (Three excellent answers, IMO)